# Tikz learning: easy tools to help

Tags: tikz-pgf, tools

Is there any app/site that can help/teach about `Tikz`? I am using *Mathpix* for mathematical formulas, I would like to have something similar.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. The easy tool that I prefer is Mathcha.

Comment: The best way to learn Ti*k*Z is *learn-by-doing*. For start I suggest to read http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf, than looks into collection of examples in https://texample.net/  and when you stuck, ask here for help :-)

Comment: Of course, it is strongly recommended to read Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, at least tutorials, then part III, and consult it when ever you need ...

Comment: https://latexdraw.com/ contains a lot of very nice tutorials, from basic to advanced.

Comment: Is this recommended https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf? I am going to start reading/studying from this manual.

Comment: Even [VisualTikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz) can be useful.